# How to return a str containing key and value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

```
def dict_to_str(d):
    """ (dict) -> str

    Return a str containing each key and value in d. Keys and values are
    separated by a space. Each key-value pair is separated by a comma.

    >>> dict_to_str({3: 4, 5: 6})
    '3 4,5 6'
    """
```

How would I write the body of this function?

so far, I have the following:

```
for values in d.values():
    print(values)
for items in dict.keys(d):
    print(items)
```

but I don't know how I would make it so it comes up in the right format. I am wanting to make each value/item a list, so I can coordinate for example, value[0] and item[0], value[1] and item[1] and so on

Comment: Please add your attempts to the question. :)

Comment: Why do you need this function? (Is it homework?)

Comment: thanks, I've added my attempts

it is an exercise that should have been finished in tutorials (for our learning purposes). I am trying to catch up on the tutorials, I've found that seeing correct bodies to functions helps as I can try to decipher what it's doing (otherwise I am completely lost and can spend a long time on a function to no avail)

Comment: You may need to go over some early exercises before tackling this one. A function that just calls `print` without returning anything can't possibly be the answer here; you need to accumulate an answer somehow and return it at the end. If you don't understand how to do that, you're not going to be able to solve this. Also, the fact that you're using `dict.keys(d)` instead of `d.keys()` (or just `d`), that you're mixing up items and keys, etc. imply other areas you're confused about.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a list comprehension:

```
','.join([' '.join(map(str, item)) for item in d.iteritems()])
```

On Python 3, replace `.iteritems()` with `.items()`. `map()` is used to make sure both keys and values are strings before joining.

Demo:

```
>>> d = {3: 4, 5: 6}
>>> ','.join([' '.join(map(str, item)) for item in d.iteritems()])
'3 4,5 6'
```

Note that the order will be arbitrary; dictionaries do not have a set ordering (instead the order depends on the insertion and deletion history of the keys).

Wrapping this in a function is left as exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

```
def dict_to_str(d):
    lDKeys = d.keys()
    lDValues = d.values()
    sD = ','.join([lDKeys[i]+' '+lDValues[i] for i in range(len(d))])
    return sD
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version that decomposes my list comprehension is:

```
def dict_to_str(d):
    lDKeys = d.keys()
    lDValues = d.values()
    lD = []
    for i in range(len(d)):
        lD.append(lDKeys[i]+' '+lDValues[i])
    sD = ','.join(lD)
    return sD
```